# Two conditional formatting rules

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to set up two conditional formatting rules:

- One in which when cell B3 is empty, the corresponding cell (J3) stays its current color.
- The second rule is when a date that is put in cell B3 that is 90 days or more from today's date, the corresponding cell (J3) turns red.

Can someone help please?

Comment: This sounds like excel, not .net

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the first rule; it sounds like when the cell is empty do nothing, which is the same as a date that's less than 90 days from today's date. Seems redundant.  Also, can you post what you have in your rules so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please select J3 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(ABS(B3-TODAY())>89,B3<>"")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd> with red formatting, OK, OK.

Note this assumes the formatting in J3 is not set by Conditional Formatting when B3 is blank and that "90 days or more from today's date" is either earlier or later than today.